# Prepare statement with PIVOT like subquery table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement, pivot-table

I have table as you can see below. The full query what i created is on this link on sqlfiddle [table with all days](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3206d/39). In query i use concat function for preparing query for PIVOT table with dates like column name and assing to variable @sql. The result you can see below in **result1**, this table will be subtable of another query and in next concat function i prepare statement which will compare dates between them "if the prices are same so the value will 0 in other way it will be 1" and assing to variable @sql2 (**result2**). With this query on [table with all days](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3206d/39) everything works, but when i will delete for example date '2014-02-05' from that table it doesn't work as you can see in another link [table with deleted date](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6dd31/1). I know i can write WHERE statement but i need it dynamicaly (because i don't know which date will be missed. Maybe if you know better solution you can write it me too. Thanks for your help

```
 id    name        date        price
------------------------------------
|1 | 'produkt1'| '2014-02-01'| 1250|
|2 | 'produkt1'| '2014-02-02'| 1250|
|3 | 'produkt1'| '2014-02-03'| 1210|
|4 | 'produkt1'| '2014-02-04'| 1230|
|5 | 'produkt1'| '2014-02-05'| 1230|
|6 | 'produkt1'| '2014-02-06'| null|
|7 | 'produkt1'| '2014-02-07'| 1230|
|8 | 'produkt1'| '2014-02-08'| 1230|
|9 | 'produkt2'| '2014-02-01'| 1350|
|10| 'produkt2'| '2014-02-02'| 1220|
|11| 'produkt2'| '2014-02-03'| 1240|
|12| 'produkt2'| '2014-02-04'| 1240|
|13| 'produkt2'| '2014-02-05'| 1240|
|14| 'produkt2'| '2014-02-06'| null|
|15| 'produkt2'| '2014-02-07'| null|
|16| 'produkt2'| '2014-02-08'| 1240|
```

**result1 - PIVOT TABLE**

```
name      | 2014-02-01 | 2014-02-02 | 2014-02-03 | 2014-02-04 | 2014-02-05 | 2014-02-06 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
produkt1  | 1250       |  1250      |  1210      |  1230      | 1230       | null
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
produkt2  | 1350       |  1220      |  1240      |  1240      | 1240       | null
```

**result2 - Comparing prices**

```
name      | 2014-02-01 <> 2014-02-02 | 2014-02-02 <>2014-02-03 | 2014-02-03 <> 2014-02-04| ..
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
produkt1  |            1             |           0             |            0
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
produkt2  |            0             |           0             |            1
```

Comment: The question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table is related to this question.